# не работает прием UDP пакетов Java

Tags: java, android-studio, многопоточность, udp

Есть проблема: не работает прием пакетов на клиенте. Отправка работает, прием выведен в отдельный поток, отправка тоже в отдельный поток, пробовал в одном потоке, тоже не работает.

Вот код потока приема:

```java
public class Udp_receive extends Thread {

    public static String inBuf;
    byte[] rdata = {0};
    int udp_port = 45045;
   // InetAddress adder;
    DatagramSocket ds;

    public Udp_receive() {

        try {
            ds = new DatagramSocket(45045);
          //  adder = InetAddress.getByName(MainActivity.ipPub);
        } catch (Exception e) {}

        start();
    }

    public void run() {
        byte temp = MainActivity.btndn;
        MainActivity.inBufr = inBuf;
       //while (true) {
          //  byte temp = MainActivity.btndn;
          // if (temp == 100) {
          // }
       DatagramPacket receivingPacket = new DatagramPacket(rdata, rdata.length);
       try {
            
          ds.receive(receivingPacket);

          String recData = new String(receivingPacket.getData());

          inBuf = recData ;
          Thread.sleep(200);

       } catch (Exception e) {}
        //}
    }
}
```

Comment: в качестве сервера будет использоваться ESP32

Comment: Что значит "не работает" ? Как знаете, что не работает? Одна очевидная проблема - это работа с разделяемыми переменными из разных потоков без синхронизации